# How to determine if date is in .ReceivedTime?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I wrote a script to get my own sent email list. It worked until recently.

It works for 2021/07 or older months but but it cannot get any of 2021/08 emails.

I suppose it's caused by some cache reason (maybe some of the emails don't exist in local folders yet).

```vb
Sub get_Sent_mail()

On Error Resume Next

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim nmsName As NameSpace

Dim mail As mailitem
Dim text1 As String

sent_month = "2021/8"
Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set nmsName = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
For Each mail In nmsName.Folders("abc@efd.com").Folders("inbox").Folders("Sent Emails").Items
    If InStr(mail.ReceivedTime, sent_month) <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print mail.subject
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are relying on the local settings to convert a datetime value `mail.ReceivedTime` to a string. That string might contain the month name instead of the number or a number with a without a leading 0. Or the year/month sequence can be different (m/y vs y/m)

You need to explicitly retrieve the month and year number and treat them as integers

```
If (Month(mail.ReceivedTime) = 8) AND (Year(mail.ReceivedTime) = 2021) Then
  Debug.Print mail.subject
End If
```

Worse than that, your code is extremely inefficient - it is like writing a SQL query without a WHERE clause. You really need to use `Items.Restrict`:

```
set items = nmsName.Folders("abc@efd.com").Folders("inbox").Folders("Sent Emails").Items
set restrictedItems = items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '2021/08/01' AND [ReceivedTime] < '2021/09/01'")
for each mail in restrictedItems 
  Debug.Print mail.subject
next
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry  Thanks for your suggestion!  However I tried your suggested code but the iussue remains --- it worked for  other months but not the current month,  so if Month(mail.ReceivedTime) = 7 then it works but not work if =8.......

Comment: Please show your code. And you really need to use Restrict instead of looping through all items.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry! Amazing ! Once adding the restriction code it worked ! But just for curiocity, why lack of restriction simply made it no result( I thought the inefficient code will slow the script but it just didn't work in some month...

Comment: I don't know - I'd really need to see the actual code...